# Ng-if boolean condition issue

Tags: angularjs

I trying to show button if `isNotRegistered == true` and hide nested links. And if it's `false` hide the button and show links.
Why do in my plunker all links hide?
http://plnkr.co/edit/XpwWyYKpbeUASUJpnDa0?p=preview

Comment: There is no link in your code. Post it **here** to make the question meaningful, and explain clearly what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: *"Why do in my plunker all links hide?"* - because there are no links at all?

Comment: updated my plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/XpwWyYKpbeUASUJpnDa0?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the names would turn into links... Check this out... Kindly correct me if i misinterpreted it.

```js
angular.module("App", [])
  .controller("Ctrl", function($scope){
    $scope.list = [
      {item: '1',
        isNotRegistered: false,
        children: [ 
        {name: '11'},
        {name: '12'}
        ]
      },
      {item: '2',
        isNotRegistered: true,
        children: [ 
        {name: '21'},
        {name: '22'}
        ]
      }
      ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in list">{{item.item}}
        <ul>
          <li ng-if="item.isNotRegistered" ng-repeat="child in item.children">{{child.name}}</li>
          <button ng-if="!item.isNotRegistered">Click</button>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace this

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in list">{{item.item}}
        <ul>
          <li ng-if="!item.isNotRegistered" ng-repeat="item in item.children">{{item.name}}</li>
          <button ng-if="item.isNotRegistered">Click</button>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

from this

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in list">{{item.item}}
        <ul>
          <li ng-if="!item.isNotRegistered" ng-repeat="newItems in item.children">{{newItems.name}}</li>
          <button ng-if="item.isNotRegistered">Click</button>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

the problem was previously for both ng repeat you assign value to **item**. so there was a confusion

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-show instead and avoid using same variable name at different levels. I have changes the first li item as Pitem. Below is the working for you.
All the best

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="Pitem in list">{{Pitem.item}}
        <ul>

          <li ng-show="!Pitem.isNotRegistered" ng-repeat="item in Pitem.children">{{item.name}}</li>

          <button ng-show="Pitem.isNotRegistered">Click</button>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Please mark as answer if this solves your question